# storing canvas in an object?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I wrote a class that is responsible for holding a canvas and its graphicsContext2d object.
But when I want to add that canvas object to the scene, it doesn't work.

Why isn't this code working like the out-commented code?
The object is just stored somewhere else, or what am I missing?

//EDIT2:

Problem was that tab1.getHeight() return 0.0...

//EDIT:

Well this works, but why?? I am just creating the object outside CanvasScreen instead of in it...

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500);
    CanvasScreen screen = new CanvasScreen(canvas, tab1.getHeight(), tab1.getWidth());
    screen.getContext().setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    screen.getContext().setLineWidth(5);
    screen.getContext().strokeLine(40, 10, 10, 40);


    tab1.getChildren().add(screen.getCanvas());
}
```

//OLD:

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    CanvasScreen screen = new CanvasScreen(tab1.getHeight(), tab1.getWidth());
    screen.getContext().setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    screen.getContext().setLineWidth(5);
    screen.getContext().strokeLine(40, 10, 10, 40);

//  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500);
//  canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setStroke(Color.BLUE);
//  canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setLineWidth(5);
//  canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().strokeLine(40, 10, 10, 40);

    tab1.getChildren().add(screen.getCanvas());
}
```

Comment: Could you show your CanvasScreen class?

Comment: I'm sorry the problem was the "tab1.getHeight()" somehow it is 0.0 at any time...